# What do I need to do to get it to display all of the user input/choices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display user input from the following form in a javascript/jquery alert box, with a line break in between each piece of information. I've tried implementing this jquery alert, but I am no better off than before. This is what I've got so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Questions n Shiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normanlize-signup.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>

            $('#formid').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(JSON.stringify($('#formid')));
              });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <form>

    <h1>Enter Thou'st Information</h1>

    <fieldset>

      <legend><span class="number">1</span> Your basic info</legend>

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" placeholder="Rob Neale">

    <label for="mail">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" placeholder="robneale@gmail.com">

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="robrastamanneale">

    <label>Gender/Sex:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="male" value="male" name="user_gender"><label for="under_16" class="light">Male</label>
      <br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" value="female" name="user_gender"><label for="over_16" class="light">Female</label>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

      <legend><span class="number">2</span> Your profile</legend>

      <label for="bio">Biography:</label>
    <textarea id="bio" name="user_bio" placeholder="Some words go in here ;)"></textarea>

      <label for="house">House:</label>
      <select id="house" name="user_job">
        <optgroup label="House">
          <option value="bradman">Bradman</option>
          <option value="chisholm">Chisholm</option>
          <option value="helpmann">Helpmann</option>
          <option value="mawson">Mawson</option>
          <option value="mccubbin">McCubbin</option>
          <option value="oliphant">Oliphant</option>
          <option value="sutherland">Sutherland</option>
          <option value="thiele">Thiele</option>
        </optgroup>

        </optgroup>


      </select>

      <label>Subjects</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="development" value="interest_maths" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="development">Maths C</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="design" value="interest_physics" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="design">Physics</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_chemistry" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Chemistry</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_biology" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Biology</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_marine" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Marine Biology</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_graphics" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Graphics</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_ipt" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">IPT</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_its" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">ITS</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_business" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Business</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_legal" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Legal Studies</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_engineering" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Engineering</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="business" value="interest_accoutngin" name="user_interest">
      <label class="light" for="business">Accounting</label>


    </fieldset>


    <legend><span class="number">3</span> Submit!</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" id="update" value="interest_update" name="user_update">
      <label class="light" for="update">Tick to recieve a free complimentary Elliot</label>


    <button type="submit" onclick="displayOutput()">Submit!</button>

  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: It's `FormElement.serializeArray()`. Where is `$('#formid')` anyways?

Comment: where do I put the

    FormElement.serialize()?

Comment: You must understand the basics. I suggest watching some tutorials or reading some books. You would put the results in an Element, or a bunch of Elements.

Comment: Sorry to push you, but I need a quick answer and I don't have time to read books. How do I fix it so my user input pops up in an alert form.

Comment: Bump. Need help quick

Comment: Your Subjects checkboxes should have array-style names, `name="user_interest[]"`. Otherwise, when you serialize it you'll only get one subject, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just list all the values, with `'\n'` between them to add newlines.

```
alert($("#name").val() + '\n' + $("#mail").val() + '\n' + 
      $("#password").val() + $(":radio[name=user_gender]:checked").val() + '\n' +
      $("#bio").val() + '\n' + 
      'Subjects: ' + $(":checkbox[name=user_interest]:checked").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

To roll through all elements of the form you can use `elements`

```
   function displayOutput() {
      for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].elements.length;i++)
        console.log(document.forms[0].elements[i].id +": " 
                +  document.forms[0].elements[i].value);
   }
```

This checks for `value` only, although others need to get checked for e.g.: `selected`but that is not that complicated to add.

If it is too complicated, as suggested, try this as a starting point:

```
   function displayOutput() {
      var id;
      var content;
      var elem;
      for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].elements.length;i++){
        id = document.forms[0].elements[i].id;
        if(!id)
          continue;
        elem = document.getElementById(id);
        if(elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA"){
          if(elem.type === "checkbox")
            content = (elem.checked)?"checked":"blank";
          else if(elem.type === "radio")
            content = (elem.checked)?"checked":"blank";
          else
            content = elem.value;
        } else if(elem.tagName === "SELECT"){
          content = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
        }
        console.log(id +": " + content);
     }
   }
```

It took me a couple of minutes to find out that you have multiple ids (there must be only one `id` per document)

Comment: I'll bet it's too complicated for the OP. :)

Comment: @Barmar for me, too, as it seems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps, if your form has the correct id:

```
var res = '';
$.each($('#formid').serializeArray(), function(i, v){
  res += i+':'+v+'\n';
});
alert(res);
```

Of course, `alert` is a horrible way to do this in the real World.